# In python/pandas is there a way to find a row that has a duplicate value in one column and a unique value in another?

Tags: python, pandas

For example:

Say I have a dataframe like

| Date Registered | Name | Gift |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-30 | John Doe | Money |
| 2021-10-30 | John Doe | Food |
| 2021-11-02 | Tyler Blue | Gift Card |
| 2021-11-02 | Tyler Blue | Food |
| 2021-12-01 | John Doe | Supplies |

I want to locate all indexes where an entry in name has a unique value in date. Like so:

| Date Registered | Name | Gift |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-30 | John Doe | Money |
| 2021-11-02 | Tyler Blue | Gift Card |
| 2021-12-01 | John Doe | Supplies |

I tried this:

```
name_view = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Name', 'DateTime'], keep= 'last')
def extract_name(TableName):
    return TableName.duplicated(subset=['Name']) 
extract_name(name_view)
```

But this does not get rid of all the indexes with duplicate dates. Any suggestions? I'm fine with it simply returning a list of the indexes as well, it isn't required to output the full row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give the requested output as a list of index values:

```py
print(df.reset_index().groupby(['Date Registered','Name']).first()['index'].tolist())
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 4]
```

Comment: This is what I needed, I can pass this index list into another dataframe and can go from there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You were already there with `pd.drop_duplicates()`:

```
>>> df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Date Registered', 'Name'])
  Date Registered        Name       Gift
0      2021-10-30    John Doe      Money
2      2021-11-02  Tyler Blue  Gift Card
4      2021-12-01    John Doe   Supplies
```

The indices are therefore:

```
>>> df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Date Registered', 'Name']).index
Int64Index([0, 2, 4], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: I don't think that is correct. It is just a coincidence that both rows with food are duplicates in this order. E.g switch the two rows of `Tyler Blue` and you will get `Food` in your result but OP still wants to have `Gift Card` as result, since `Food` is a duplicate

Comment: Why does it want `Gift Card` in that case? OP asks for name with a unique value for date, as `Food` is then above `Gift Card` you will get `Food` which is the desired outcome I think

Comment: Maybe I'm alone here, I think it is closed for the wrong reason, your answer and also the other answers are not what he tries to achieve. As far as I understand OP wants to drop duplicates for Names and keep that row where the value of `Gift` is in no other group of the data. Since `Food` is also present with `John Doe` it gets deleted.....and not because of `first` or `last` in `drop_duplicates`. That's why I said change the order and your results changes, but he still would want 'Gift Card` because it is the only unique value for Tyler in the data

Comment: You're correct in that this gives me the desired table output, but I also need to gather the specific indexes where the names that meet the criteria occurs. As the table will still be populated with unique name entries.

Comment: @Rabinzel OP doesn't seem to care about Gift, there is nothing about it in the description nor in the provided code.

Comment: It's just how I understood the title. Propably you are right, since I'm the only one thinking like that.

Comment: @thorscode you can get the index by doing: `.index` at the end

Answer (score 0):

Adding `.reset_index()` to the end of your "name_view" variable removed all excess rows when I ran it against your example column (*I had to change the name of the first column to make it work).

```
name_view = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Name', 'DateTime'], keep= 'last').reset_index()


def extract_name(TableName):
    return TableName.duplicated(subset=['Name']) 
extract_name(name_view)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `pd.drop_duplicates():` on what you already have

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_csv(csv_file, encoding='latin-1')

df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Date Registered', 'Name'])

print(df)
```

Comment: how is this different from my answer?

Comment: I mean, great solution, but unfortunately a duplicate ;)

Comment: Ah, sorry. Didn't realize you beat me by 2min,